# letsencrypt certbot broken

Tags: certbot

CentOS 7
apache ver 2.4
php 7.1

My certbot is broken, and I am unable to fix it.

```
[root@sw4u ~]# certbot renew
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/certbot", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 3011, in <module>
    parse_requirements(__requires__), Environment()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 626, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: cffi>=1.8,!=1.11.3
```

```
[root@sw4u ~]# certbot
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/certbot", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 3011, in <module>
    parse_requirements(__requires__), Environment()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 626, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: cffi>=1.8,!=1.11.3
```

yum install python2-acme
yum install phtyon2-certbot-*

Install Almost certbot, python2 and python3.
But I can't solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed `cffi`?

```
python3 -m venv env
source env/bin/activate
pip3 install cffi
```